# Can not compile TeXStudio’s Letter template

Tags: templates, document-classes, texstudio, letters

I have just created a new file from a template in TeXStudio. I have chosen the letter template. So I have this code generated:

```
\documentclass[]{letter}


\begin{document}
% If you want headings on subsequent pages,
% remove the ``%'' on the next line:
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{letter}{TO_ADDRESS}
\address{ADDRESS}

\opening{SALUTATION}

\signature{}

\closing{}

%enclosure listing
%\encl{}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

So far, I don't even touch the code and I can not compile this since I have these errors :

```
Missing $ inserted \opening{SALUTATION}
There's no line here to end. \opening{SALUTATION}
Missing $ inserted \opening{SALUTATION}
There's no line here to end. \closing{}
```

Any ideas why? I would like to start from this template, but I don't figure out how to fix this type of errors.

Comment: There is `TO_ADRESS` in your letter. The underscore character requires math mode, therefore the 'Missing $ inserted' error message. And `closing` should not be empty.

Comment: `\begin{letter}{TO_ADDRESS}` You need to be in math mode to print the Underscore `_`. Just remove that and test again. Or type `\_` to really print an underscore.

Comment: Ok perfect, thank you. Now I just have one error left "There's no line here to end. \closing{}". Where do you think that come from ?

Comment: @FlorentP: About `closing` see my extended first comment

Comment: Shall one of us (Johannes_B) or I add answer to close this question?

Comment: If you don't want a `\closing`, just type `\closing{\mbox{}}`

Comment: I filed a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/966/ .. It’s not really a bad bug, but there’s no reason the template shouldn’t be compilable.

Comment: @egreg, thank you for the tips ! I did as you said.

Comment: @doncherry yes that's exactly what I thought when posting this question.

Comment: @doncherry, @FlorentP: Perhaps, it is sometimes better not to use those templates provide by `TeX` editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the errors to a minimally working example...

```
\documentclass[]{letter}


\begin{document}
% If you want headings on subsequent pages,
% remove the ``%'' on the next line:
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{letter}{William Shakespeare}  % Since good old William's 450th birthday in a few days ;-)
\address{London}

\opening{Dear William}

\signature{Ben Jonson}

\closing{Well roared, lion}\relax

%enclosure listing
%\encl{}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hey Christian, I have some difficulties on another question, du you have any ideas how I can figure out to do that ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172600/48977